# CORS request not working without chrome plugin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cors

I'm trying to get quotes from the [this website](http://forismatic.com/en/api/) using this code with a GET httprequest

```
var jsonObj;
var httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

var processJson = function (json) 
{
    jsonObj = JSON.parse(json);
    document.getElementById("quote-text").innerHTML = jsonObj.quoteText;
    document.getElementById("quote-author").innerHTML = jsonObj.quoteAuthor;
}


httpReq.onload = function() 
{
    if (httpReq.status === 200)
    {
        processJson(this.response);    
    }        
};
httpReq.open("GET", "http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en", true);
httpReq.send();
```

The only thing is that this piece of code only works with a CORS plugin installed on Chrome, otherwise it won't work. The error it gives me is the following:

*MLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:64290' is therefore not allowed access.*

Any clue? Thank you!

Comment: You have to use the `jsonp` part of the API: http://api.forismatic.com/api/jsonp/ (<- view source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They clearly don't know what CORS is if they are using JSONP.
JSONP is a format when you include a script with a callback, the risk then is that data can leak and they can insert any code into your page

```js
var loadJSONP = (function(){
  var unique = 0;
  return function(url, callback, context) {
    // INIT
    var name = "_jsonp_" + unique++;
    if (url.match(/\?/)) url += "&jsonp="+name;
    else url += "?callback="+name;

    // Create script
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;

    // Setup handler
    window[name] = function(data){
      callback.call((context || window), data);
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].removeChild(script);
      script = null;
      delete window[name];
    };

    // Load JSON
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  };
})();


loadJSONP(
  'http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=jsonp&lang=en',
   function(data) {
     console.log(data);
   }
);
```

Another possible solution is to use something like a cors proxy - there are a few out there but you could build your own

```js
var cors = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
var url = "http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en"

fetch(cors + url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => console.log(json))
```

The risk with a cors proxy is that they can spy on data that are passing through. You also depend on a extra service that could go down anytime

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I thought of using a CORS proxy, but I read somewhere that it is a sort of a "hacky" way to get requests from a website, since it could potentially get info from them even if they don't enable a CORS implementation on their server? Could you expand on that? Would it be ok to use as proxy? And what would be the advantage/disadvantage over Jsonp?

Comment: Read this: [security risks with jsonp](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23438/security-risks-with-jsonp) - cors proxy is not that dangerous if you only request public information like a weather information. what you maybe want to avoid with a cors proxy could be sending auth/api-key headers along with the request

Comment: Nevermind, I've figured it out! Thank you again, I'll accept the answer :)

Comment: [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) is the new ajax API (pure js)